# how can I prettify a not serializable python object without eval

Tags: python, json

```
resp = self.es.search(**params)
print(json.dumps(resp), indent=2, sort_keys=True))
TypeError: Object of type ObjectApiResponse is not JSON serializable
```

If I `str(object)` I can see it but as a string with no layout:

```
print(json.dumps(str(resp), indent=2, sort_keys=True)
"{'took': 667, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, \
'failed': 0}, 'hits': {'total': {'value': 2182, 'relation': 'eq'}, ......."
```

Another way is to use the ugly eval:

```
resp2 = eval(str(resp))
print(json.dumps(resp2, indent=2, sort_keys=True))
{
  "_shards": {
  :
  },
  "aggregations": {
  :
  },
  "hits": {
  :
  },
  "timed_out": false,
  "took": 7
}
```

But sonar complains big time and thus fails the ci pipeline.

So how do I json prettify the resp object?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] that doesn't require us to have other code (not provided by the question) that generates an `ObjectApiResponse` to test proposed solutions?

Comment: it is https://pypi.org/project/elasticsearch/ `elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.search(**params)`, quite hard to make a minimal example, it is the kibana inspect search request json dump

Answer (score 1):

`eval()` throws Sonar warnings because it can run arbitrary code, and is thus a security risk.

`ast.literal_eval()` doesn't run arbitrary code -- it *only* parses Python literals; thus, it's safe to use.

```
import ast
resp2 = ast.literal_eval(str(resp))
print(json.dumps(resp2, indent=2, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: I knew there was a module for it, Thanks @Charles Duffy